# Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $F(x,y)= \|f(x)-f(y)\| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on some exam practice questions, and this one seems quite hard. I would greatly appreciate some help with it.

Here is the complete question.

> Let $ B \subseteq \mathbb{R^d} $ be a bounded and closed set, and let
>   $f:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R^N}$ be continous.
>
> Set $B \times B := \{(x,y) : x,y \in B \} \subseteq \mathbb{R^d} \times  \mathbb{R^d} = \mathbb{R^{2d}} $
>    and define $F,h: B \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $
>    by $$F(x,y):= ||f(x)-f(y)|| $$ and 
>   $$h(x,y):= ||x-y||$$ for all $(x,y) \in B \times B$. The functions $F$
>   and $h$ are continuous functions (do not require proof).
>
> Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By considering the continuous function $h$ on the
>   set $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$,
>
> Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$F(x,y)= ||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon $$
>    for all $(x,y) \in B \times B$ such that $ h(x,y)=||x-y|| < \delta$.
>    (By the definition of continuity this means that
>   $\delta$ can be chosen independently of $x \in B$).

Here is my very humble attempt to start this question:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be fixed, such that $$F(x,y)= ||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon $$ with $x,y \in [\epsilon, \infty) \in B \times B$

Then by the definition of continuity, there exists $\delta > 0 $ such that $ ||x-y|| < \delta$

Now consider $h$ on the set $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$. Then $ h(x,y)=||x-y|| < \delta$ for the same $x,y$ as above...

Now I'm not sure where to go with it. I know it's very far from correct, so would greatly appreciate some help!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction this is not true.

Then for each $n$ you can find some $x_n,y_n$ such that 
$$F(x_n,y_n) > \epsilon \,,$$
$$h(x_n,y_n) <\frac{1}{n} \,.$$

Now, since $B$ is bounded an closed, $x_n$ must have a convergent subsequence 
$$x_{k_n} \to x \,.$$

Same way $y_{k_n}$ has a convergent subsequence $y_{l_n} \to y$. Now 
$$(x_{l_n},y_{l_n}) \to (x,y)$$
and $F,h$ are continuous. Then you get a contradiction by applying the limits to the above inequalities.

**Second proof**

As $F$ is continuous, $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ is closed in $B$ hence $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ is closed and bounded in $R^n$.

Therefore, as $h$ is continuous, the statement below you covered is true:

- $h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space])$ is compact in $R$.
- $h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space])$ is closed and bounded  in $R$.
- $h: F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space] \to R$ attains its absolute minimum.

Now, it is easy to prove that $0 \notin h: F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$. Therefore, any of the three statements above imply that there exists some $\delta$ such that $(0, \delta) \cap h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]) =\emptyset$, which is exactly what you need to prove.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can I just ask a few questions: firstly, how did you get $h(x_n,y_n) <\frac{1}{n} $? Also the question says to consider $h$ on the set $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$, have we done that here?

Comment: @user153663 My proof is by contradiction, use $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ and what it means for the statement to be false... And I will add details for a proof as asked.

Comment: @user153663 done...

Comment: Thanks again, how can we say $0 \notin h: F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$? Could we not say, pick $x=y$ with $x,y \in [\epsilon,\infty)$ Wouldn't this make $h = 0$? Or do you mean that $0$ is not in the domain of $h$? Also, how would I relate  $(0, \delta) \cap h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]) =\emptyset$ back to that $$F(x,y) < \epsilon$$?

Comment: @user153663 $h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space])$ means the image of the set $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space])$. In other words it is the RANGE of the function $h: F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space] \to R$...

Comment: @user153663 And if $0 \in h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space])$ then it means there exists some $(x,y) \in F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ such that $h(x,y)=0$. As you observed $x=y$ works, but this is the only situation: if $h(x,y)=0$ you must have $x=y$. On another hand you also have $(x,y) \in F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ which means $$F(x,y) > \epsilon $$ But $x=y$.......

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realised that was a stupid question, so deleted it. But I'm still trying to understand, if we show that there is some $\delta$ such that $(0, \delta) \cap h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]) $ is empty - how does that prove that there exists a $\delta$ such that $F(x,y)=||f(x)-F(y)||< \epsilon$, such that $g(x,y)=||x-y||<\delta$? (Sorry! I'm obviously an idiot!)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your latest comment before I posted that. Reading and thinking now..

Comment: I think I may be finally getting it. So we are proving by contradiction. We assume that for $\delta > 0$, $F(x,y) > \epsilon$, for a fixed $\epsilon$. Then if we consider $$h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$$, if $0$ is in the image $\implies x=y$. But we also have $x,y$ in the image of $F$. If $x=y, \implies F(x,y) = 0$. This contradicts that $F(x,y) > \epsilon$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user153663 Yes.

Comment: Thanks for all you help! One last thing, should the $\epsilon$ in $F(x,y)>\epsilon$ be different from the one in $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$? I don't think they are related are they?

Comment: They are related. Note that saying $(x,y) \in F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ is the same as saying $F(x,y) \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: oh yep, right that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, can I just ask as well: So from my above argument, after deriving the contradiction that $F(x,y) \ge \epsilon$, would it be correct to say then that for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$ if $F(x,y) < \epsilon$ then there exists a $\delta$ such that $h(x,y) < \delta$? Can I just immediately conclude that? Somehow, I feel like that is not quite enough. Thanks for any further feedback you can give me!

Comment: @user153663 Not immediately, the key is the fact that $h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space])$ is closed, and here is where you need one of the three bulleted  conditions... Once you conclude that this is closed, its complement must be open, and you just argued that $0$ is in the complement... Therefore the complement contains some interval $(-\delta, \delta)$....

Comment: Ah ok. I think I am getting closer..So considering $h$ on $h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)]$ as you noted is the same as saying $F(x,y) \ge \epsilon$. Now since $B$ is closed and $F$ and $h$ are continuous $\implies F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)]$ is closed & bded $\implies h(F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)]$ is closed. So it's complement is open. $0$ is in the complement (some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ So if $g(x,y)<\delta$ then it follows that $F(x,y)<\epsilon$. Since this $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this means that for any $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$...Would this be a complete answer?

Comment: Also, just to clarify - in your answer under 'Second Proof' - did you mean $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb(R^d)$? As opposed to $\mathbb(R^d)$?

Comment: As opposed to $\mathbb(R^N)$ Sorry.

Comment: Sorry again, but since $B$ is closed and bounded, would this also imply that $F^{-1}[\space[\epsilon,\infty)\space]$ is closed and bounded as well?